# how can i filter this array in php?

Tags: php

I have following array. i want to differentiate array

```
[role_code] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [16] => CA
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [16] => TA
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [16] => GA
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [17] => CA
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [17] => GA
                )
    )
```

How can i get this array like following

```
Array
(
    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => CA
            [1] => TA
            [2] => TA

        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => TA
            [1] => GA
        ) 

)
```

I have done following code but it get this array

```
Array
(
    [16] => CA
)
Array
(
    [16] => TA
)
Array
(
    [16] => GA
)
Array
(
    [17] => CA
)
Array
(
    [17] => GA
)
```

Answer (score 4):

See online example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/013b3931173209a2e8f74c7e9d50b2c4eed95b37)

```
<?php
//your array
$array = [
    [16 => 'CA'],
    [16 => 'TA'],
    [16 => 'GA'],
    [17 => 'CA'],
    [17 => 'GA']
];

//variable to result
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        $result[$k][] = $v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple loop do the job.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($role_code as $subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $key => $val) {
            $newArray[$key][] = $val;
    }
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
'role_code' => Array(0 => Array(16 => 'CA'),1 => Array(16 => 'TA'), 2 => Array(16 => 'GA'),3 => Array(17 => 'CA'),4 => Array(17 => 'GA')));
foreach($array[role_code] as $key=>$smallArray)
{
    foreach($smallArray as $keySmallArray=>$value){
        $newArray[$keySmallArray][] = $value;
    }
}
print_r("<pre>");
print_r($newArray);
print_r("</pre>");
```